# How to retrieve all stored fields from Core with SolrJ

Tags: solrj

Is it possible to retrieve all stored fields from certain Core using SolrJ client ?

e.g. `<field name="author" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>`

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the information about the fields using SolrJ client for the specific core.

Use the following code snippet to retrieve.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
    import org.apache.solr.common.params.CommonParams;
    import org.apache.solr.common.util.NamedList;
    import org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap;



    SolrServer solrCore = new HttpSolrServer("http://{host:port}/solr/core-name");
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.add(CommonParams.QT, "/schema/fields");
    QueryResponse response = solrCore.query(query);
    NamedList responseHeader = response.getResponseHeader();
    ArrayList<SimpleOrderedMap> fields = (ArrayList<SimpleOrderedMap>) response.getResponse().get("fields");
    for (SimpleOrderedMap field : fields) {
        Object fieldName = field.get("name");
        Object fieldType = field.get("type");
        Object isIndexed = field.get("indexed");
        Object isStored = field.get("stored");
        // you can use other attributes here.

        System.out.println(field.toString());
    }
```

Please note i am using 4.10.2 version of SolrJ.

Thanks,

Shiva Kumar SS